# yii2 dependent validation for min/max

Tags: validation, yii2

i need to create dependent validation. When i select option in dropdown, i must get value from database (min and max sum).
My code for one option from dropdown:

```
       [
            ['sum'], 
            'number',
            'min' => HdbkPaymentMethod::getMethodSumMinById(1),
            'max' => HdbkPaymentMethod::getMethodSumMaxById(1),
            'when' => function($model, $attribute) {
                $model->method_id == 1;
            }, 
            'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
                return $('#payment-method_id').val() == 1;
            }"
        ],
```

but it must be for many options in dropdownlist. Help me pls.

Comment: `[['sum' ,'option1' ,'option2'],............] `

Comment: can u give me more advanced example, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question, you want the value of `sum` to be within a range, specified by `max` and `min`. To do this you need functions for `max` and `min`. Alternatively, if, as we suspect, `max` and `min` can only be numeric values, you need an [inline validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#inline-validators), or a user defined validator

```
[
    ['sum'], 
    'validateSum'
],
```

then in your model add a validator;

```
public function validateSum($attribute, $params){
    if ($this->$attribute < HdbkPaymentMethod::getMethodSumMinById($this->method_id){
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Sum is too small');
    }
if ($this->$attribute > HdbkPaymentMethod::getMethodSumMaxById($this->method_id){
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Sum is too big');
    }
}
```

Sorry, I've not tested this but it seems like the correcdt approach. I'm not sure how you would implement client-side validation for this arrangement though!

Comment: if i'm right - min/max cant be a function, just integer|float value. error: `Object of class Closure could not be converted to string`

Comment: Hmm, I've not tried it but you may be right @fisher. In that case you'll need an inline validator http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#inline-validators. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: @Fisher if this or any other answer answered your question, would you be so kind as to accept the answer? It will help other users of the site to see which answer was the right one for your situation